# ACLs Permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions, acl

Assume this is the permission I set to `file.sh`

```
$ getfacl file.sh
# file: file.sh
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rwx
user:test:r-x           #effective:--x
group::r-x          #effective:--x
mask::--x
other::---
```

Then I change user to `test`, I think the user should be capable to execute the `file.sh`.

However, I got the permission denied.

```
$ su test
> Password:
$ bash file.sh
> bash: file.sh: Permission denied
```